# woocommerce product showing two "Add to Cart" button on responsive mobile/tablet view?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin, It is showing products details on desktop view is correct but when i switch on mobile view or tablet(i.e. responsive) view then it shows two "Add to Cart" button for one product.

Comment: This is very likely a CSS issue - have a look at what css properties are being applied via Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Its not a CSS issue, I think the "Add to cart" button called two time. I am new for woocommerce so will you tell me from which file the single product details showing? So i can check the code.

Comment: Is this a fresh install? There aren't ever 2 Add-To-Cart buttons rendered by default. Were you able to find it, given the user's answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Single product is displayed from wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product.php

This file (wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-single-product.php) is called from single-product.php for adding content and add-to-cart button on single product page.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggeling with this, add this code to wordpress > wp-content > plugins > woocommerce.php
in function WC() right before return WooCommerce::inherit();

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

this will remove the button.

Comment: It's not recommended to make any edits in your plugin files, or they will be lost when you update to new version. 
However you can add this code in your theme functions for example and it will still work.

Comment: Thank for the clarification,