# Remove code html to wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning to all, I have a problem with a plug for woocommerce, in that inserts a double "buy" button on each product. To work around this problem, I have solved css for now, but unfortunately these do not remove the html code, I was wondering if there is a way to remove the html code through a function in the function file.

Thanks in advance to those who want to answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these hooks`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 20);`

Comment: inserting the code as indicated in this case, instead, works well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738937/woocommerce-product-showing-two-add-to-cart-button-on-responsive-mobile-tablet

but at this point I would like to ask how to do the same thing from the function file so as not to have to repeat the operation with each woocommerce update

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: did you try adding in your functions.php where the activated theme is ? Try again i edited my answer added priority "20"

Comment: no unfortunately from file function does not work, not even with priority 20

Comment: create a function in functions.php and put those in a function and add an action hook. you can find woo commerce action hooks from here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately I do not understand anything :)